# Can I use h.264 codec inside .mp4 container for my website

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I would like to use h.264 as the codec  inside .mp4 container for my user uploaded videos for my website. But I saw somewhere that h.264 is non free. I am unsure whether I can use this technology or not. My question whether I can use it to compress my user uploaded videos in my website? If yes, then its great. And if no, what other solution can I go with? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I'm sorry, but the about in Stackoverflow has this "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers". And since this is someone related with stackoverflow's about, I thought I could ask from you guys. Anyways, can you answer the question?

Comment: There is no programming involved with this question, you could try http://video.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: See: [Is there a Stack Exchange site for Law Questions? If not, why not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently distribution of free content does not require licensing. There were plans to also require license fees from free content distributors after 2015.

http://www.engadget.com/2010/05/04/know-your-rights-h-264-patent-licensing-and-you/

However, that doesn't seem to have happened:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Patent_licensing

> "On August 26, 2010, MPEG LA announced that H.264 encoded internet
>   video that is free to end users will never be charged royalties.[17]
>   All other royalties remain in place, such as royalties for products
>   that decode and encode H.264 video as well as to operators of free
>   television and subscription channels.[18] The license terms are
>   updated in 5-year blocks.[19]"

So unless your content is free, either you have to pay the royalties or forfeit IE support. (IE ONLY supports H.264) If you don't need IE (or Safari on iOS), then VP8 would be the way to go.

Disclaimer: If you want sound legal advice, get a lawyer. This isn't that.

Comment: This is merely an interpretation. The web site you linked to says "H.264 free distribution will be royalty-free until at least 2015, after which MPEG-LA may consider applying a different business model, which hasn't yet been defined".